# Calculate sum of numbers from text file

Tags: java, android, text-files

I'm trying to read and calculate some values within a .txt file but pressing the totalbutton doesn't seem to do anything. 
The content of the text file looks like this:

> 1
>  2
>  3
>  4
>  5
>  6

This is some code I've written. It should be able to specify the file's name when it saves it in .txt then get the name of the file and sum it's contents. 
However pushing the total button doesn't

```
pushBtn.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                CharSequence date = android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", new java.util.Date());
              fileEditText = findViewById(R.id.fileEditText);

                try {
                    FileOutputStream fileout = openFileOutput(fileEditText.getText() + ".txt", MODE_APPEND);
                    OutputStreamWriter outputWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileout);
                    outputWriter.write(numbeditText.getText().toString() + "\n");
                    outputWriter.flush();
                    outputWriter.close();

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Έγινε ενημέρωση!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //**code ends here**

                return true;
            }
        });

        totalbutton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                try{
                    File f = new File(fileEditText+ ".txt");
                    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);
                    int sum = 0;
                    while (scanner.hasNext()){
                        sum += scanner.nextInt();
                    }
                    System.out.println("Sum:"+sum);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), sum,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }catch(Exception err){
                    err.printStackTrace();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: You should add a breakpoint to see if you're entering your function or not...

Comment: And what exactly is wrong with the code you've written?

Comment: @JoeC By pressing the totalButton it should show the total number of the items inside the text file to the screen but it does not show anything.

Comment: Here how to use debugging https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html

Comment: Debugging this does not solve the issue, I just want to read the integer numbers written in the file and get a total by summing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem was the directory the file was in, it couldn't find it thus nothing was printed in my text view.
After messing with it for a couple of hours I used:

`System.out.println("Sum:"+sum)`
and found out it was actually working but it wouldn't .setText. I added the line:
`totalTextView.setText(Integer.toString(sum));`
and finally it started working as it should. Hopefully this will help others with same issues.